# Fetch the value of the data using Select Dropdown after Update Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I cannot fetch the value of the data after I store or created it .. I want to fetch the data in `edit.blade.php` after I created it. I used the `old` function method but it didnt work

My ***Controller***

```
  public function edit($id)
    {
        $movieSubs = MovieSubtitle::find($id);

        $movieTitle = Movie::all()->pluck('title','id');

        return view('admin.subtitles.edit', compact('movieSubs','movieTitle'));
    }
```

My **`edit.blade.php`** - here is where I want to fetch the data that I use `old`

```
       {{ Form::select('movieTitle',  $movieTitle, old('movie_id', $movieTitle) ,['class' => 'form-control'])}}<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an input with the name `movie_id`? In my understanding, the dropdown `movieTitle` already contains the ID of the movie so this might work better.

```
{{ Form::select('movieTitle', $movieTitle, old('movieTitle'), ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```